# RIA: "Use local IIS Web server"

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis, ria

I know I've had this problem when I started working with Silverlight, but I can't for the life of me remember how to fix it.

I created a new RIA service application using the standard tutorial, added a table from the database and added a grid to display the results. Works great. Now I pull open the Web properties and change the web project to "use local IIS Web server". Suddenly the application will load up and give me the friendly "NotFound" error.

Please, someone remind me what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently, and resolved it with help from [this post on the silverlight.net forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/146135.aspx).

Basically, I had Windows authentication and annonymous access enabled at the same time, and I need to disable windows authentication and restart IIS.

John

Comment: I'll have to take a look at that post more closely when I've got some time. Thought it seems as though the service can't be found at all once I switch to using IIS. I'll update as soon as I have a chance to play with it some more.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the missing part is but I always start with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) as will show the messages going across the wire. The actual messages can contains far more useful that the browser is hiding from the Silverlight plugin

Comment: I'm pretty sure it had something to do with the WCF services. Maybe the Silverlight project was still referencing the Dev Service. Does that sound about right? In which case, how do I go about updating my service references when I'm using RIA?